# Does "autoWebView" APPIUM capability guarantee correct WEB_VIEW out of multiple webviews ,in relation to cordova app?

Tags: cordova, appium, appium-ios

I am working on automating a iOS app using Appium-Java.

In appium documentation it was mentioned that- "autoWebView" APPIUM capability should be used for Cordova based app

In our case, app keeps on stacking multiple WebViews, as the user goes on navigating the screens.
And in that case normally I have 1 Native View & 3-4 WebViews.
So if I set autoWebView, will it gurantee that- it will always point to correct webview (i.e. the webview, which contains HTML for current page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For our unique requirement (Cordova based Hybrid app creating Multiple webviews), I have created a reusable function to point to intended WebView:

```
 public boolean switchToMeaningfulWEBVIEWUsingPageTitle(final String title) {
    Set<String> contextNames = appiumDriver.getContextHandles();
    List<MobileElement> elements = null;

    String defaultContext = appiumDriver.getContext();

    for (String contextName : contextNames) {
            System.err.println("\n ** DEBUG: contextName = "+contextName);
        appiumDriver.context(contextName);
        appiumDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
            String metaTitle = appiumDriver.getTitle();
            if (metaTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(title)) {
                if(appiumDriver.getPageSource().trim().contains("<body></body></html>")) {
                    continue;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
   appiumDriver.context(defaultContext);
    return false;
}
```

Basically when we've to some operation on WebView of the latest page, we toggle to concerned webView from Stack of webviews.
Html Title is used as reference, as we try to keep it unique but something else could also be used for unique reference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using **ios_webkit_debug_proxy** to handle webview embedded in ios native app. Also switch the context accordingly in your script whenever the app pages change(**"NATIVE" or "WEBVIEW"**).

Have a look at this link https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy

Comment: Do you have a Java snippet for this? Thanks

Comment: driver.context("WEBVIEW"); //set context to native  driver.findElement("...").click(); // perform your operation

Comment: We have one NATIVE view and multiple WEBVIEWS stacked as we navigate down in the system. So, pointing to right WEBVIEW of the current screen is important & I am facing challenge over there.